# Community-compiled errata for Bertozzi and Majda's "Vorticity and Incompressible Flow"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, big-list, fluid-dynamics, regularity-theory-of-pdes

While this is a great book, I think there isn't an errata for Bertozzi and Majda's "Vorticity and Incompressible Flow", so can we compile a list of errors here? Since this book is a classic reference in fluid dynamics/PDEs, I think such a list would be very useful.

(Or, if an errata is maintained by the author(s), please tell me where!)

One error I found : on page 130, they apply Hölder's inequality on $\|D^\beta u D^{\alpha-\beta} v\|_0$ (the $\|\cdot \|_0$ is an $L^2$ norm on $\mathbb R^n$) with exponents $ p=2m/|\beta|,\ q = 2m/|\alpha - \beta|$. (Here $\beta\le\alpha$ are multi-indices with $|\alpha| \le m$) But unless $|\alpha|=m$,
$$ \frac1p + \frac1q = \frac{|\beta|+|\alpha-\beta|}{2m} = \frac{|\alpha|}{2m}\neq \frac12. $$
Instead, the exponents $ p=2|\alpha|/|\beta|,\ q = 2|\alpha|/|\alpha - \beta|$ should be used.

Comment: Reading this book now, our library copy has a huge number of corrections written in by various people who have read the book and I have added my own. Perhaps check out your library copy? I think having a community errata page would be great.

Comment: @KyleC unfortunately my copy was quite pristine aside from my own notes :)